# How to disable data observation in vue.js component property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to create a Vue.js component that receives properties from its parent component, e.g.:

```
<table-cell :value="foo" format="date" />
```

Because `value` and `format` are defined as properties, Vue will automatically register observers to their values. That is fine in general, but for my use case I positively know those values are not going to change so they don't need to be observed.

Given that my table cell component can be in a table with, say, 1,000 rows and 10 columns, those 2 properties will create 20,000 observers, and I want to avoid all this overhead (and my real table cell component has more complex properties).

Is there any way to disable a component property from being observed in order to avoid wasting CPU & memory resources?

**Update:**
I have found a low-level solution with the *functional* component approach, explained here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components

I have tested it with this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/12143/

I wonder if that is the correct approach...

Answer (score 1):

Pass it with custom data I think like `<your-component :data-value='foo' :data-format='date'>`

It will do what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work: you are just adding a reference to a dynamic property, which will still be observed, even if you delete `this.dinamicProp`.

Comment: use slot and pass static data in slot ?

Comment: The slot option could work for a single & text-only property. If I need to pass several properties and some of them may be objects, I would have to parse complex text, and that would defeat the original purpose.

Comment: pass as custom data.

Comment: also, you can use NAMED slots which would enable you to use multiple data

Comment: You are right, and that may be a useful workaround in some cases :-).

Comment: Upvoted your reply, but I am still looking for something more powerful, so I am not marking it as solved.